# How to add camera button to UIImageView

Tags: swift, camera, uiimageview

I would like to add a background image to a `UIImageView`. At the moment, in the empty frame of the `UIImageView` I have a `tapGestureRcognizer` to open the camera.

```
let imageView = whiskyPicture
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(DataInsertController.imageTapped(_:)))
    imageView!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now I would like to add a background image in the `UIImageView`, that the user can see where to tap. The best thing would be to add the camera icon of iOS to the UIImage. After picking a photo, the background image should be gone.

Any advice how to do that?

Storyboard looks like this:

[image: DataInsertViewController Storyboard]

In the `UIImageView` I would like to add a background image.

Comment: what you mean by background image? can u show your storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `imageView`just set the camera image directly and set the `Mode` property to `Center`. Just like this image

[image]

Now in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method just change the `contentMode` of `imageView` to what you want like `Scale To Fill`, `Aspect Fit`, `Aspect Fill`, etc.

Comment: Not yet, the picture is showed in storyboard, but when I run the app, no matter if I run it on device or simulator, there's not picture

Comment: Can you add that both image in question, with storyboard and simulator one?

Comment: It is like in the picture above, there's just a blank image view, no background picture

Comment: Got it. I did it programmatically:    imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"picture"). That works

Answer (score 0):

First, either design or search for a camera image and add it to your image assets. Assuming you name your file to camera.jpg, in your storyboard set the image to camera.jpg. So that on load, you will see that image.

Now when you are done with taking a photo, you want to replace camera.jpg with your "taken" photo.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!) {
    let tempImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    myImageView.image = tempImage

    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Comment: I get in the first line an error, that editingInfo is a use of unresolved identifier. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your class.

```
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController!

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //Makes the camera pops up

    if imagePicker == nil { 
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) }

}
```

Now the use can take a picture, and the picture will be shown in the imageView. Hope I'va understand the question correctly